# "Start by creating and opening a systemd socket file for Gunicorn with sudo privileges" (directory to this file does not *appear* to exist)

Tags: gunicorn, digital-ocean, systemd, django-deployment

I am working on a server running ubuntu 18.04. This digital ocean tutorial on django deployment(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) is telling me to do the following:
"We’re now finished configuring our Django application. We can back out of our virtual environment by typing:

`(env): deactivate`" I am familiar with virtual environments, I did this. Now for the part I am not at all familiar with:
"Start by creating and opening a systemd socket file for Gunicorn with sudo privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket
```

"

First, since I just deactivated my env, I am now at `justin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01:~$`. If I `ls` I only see the `project` folder I created which holds the virtualenv, the python project, manage.py and the static directory. Nowhere can I find this

```
/etc/systemd/system/
```

directory and the command they are telling me to use cannot create directories, only files. So I am very confused, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc` doesn't live inside `~`. Try `ls /etc` to see what's already in that directory. If you need to create that directory, you can do so wih `sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/` (the `-p` flag is to make sure that, in case `systemd` is also not present under `etc`, it will get created).

Comment: `ls /etc` showed a folder with a whole lot of contents. Is this a hidden folder?

Comment: It's not a hidden folder, it's just a folder not under `~`. Note that `~` maps to `/home/<user>` (in your case I believe it will be `/home/justin`). So `etc` and `home` are sibling folders, and by using `ls .` from `home/justin` it will therefore not be shown.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Gabriela. I was stuck on this for close to 2 hours now. I now wrote to the file successfully, on to the next step...